# Using a variable in group-starting-with

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I have a stylesheet designed to add some structure which currently looks like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook" xpath-default-namespace="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="book">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="@*">
            <xsl:copy/>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:copy-of select="info"/>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="chapnumber">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="current-group()[1]/name() = 'chapnumber'">
                    <xsl:variable name="chapter_number" select="replace(., '.*([0-9]).*', '$1')"/>
                    <chapter label="{$chapter_number}">
                        <xsl:call-template name="nest_head1">
                            <xsl:with-param name="working_group" select="current-group() except ."/>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                    </chapter>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:call-template name="nest_head1">
                        <xsl:with-param name="working_group" select="current-group() except ."/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="nest_head1">
    <xsl:param name="working_group"/>

    <xsl:for-each-group select="$working_group" group-starting-with="head1">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="current-group()[1]/name() = 'head1'">
                <section>
                    <xsl:call-template name="nest_head2">
                        <xsl:with-param name="working_group" select="current-group()"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </section>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:call-template name="nest_head2">
                    <xsl:with-param name="working_group" select="current-group()"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="nest_head2">
    <xsl:param name="working_group"/>

    <xsl:for-each-group select="$working_group" group-starting-with="head2">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="current-group()[1]/name() = 'head2'">
                <section>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                </section>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="head1|head2|head3|head4|head5">
    <info>
        <title>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </title>
    </info>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="chaptitle">
    <info>
        <title>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </title>
    </info>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="italic">
    <emphasis role="italic">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </emphasis>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="bold">
    <emphasis role="bold">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </emphasis>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="@*">
            <xsl:copy/>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I dislike how each heading level has it's own template (especially as there may in theory be many more levels of headings) and thought it could be condensed to a single, more usable template with a variable for the heading level, like so:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook" xpath-default-namespace="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="book">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="@*">
            <xsl:copy/>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:copy-of select="info"/>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="chapnumber">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="current-group()[1]/name() = 'chapnumber'">
                    <xsl:variable name="chapter_number" select="replace(., '.*([0-9]).*', '$1')"/>
                    <chapter label="{$chapter_number}">
                        <xsl:call-template name="nest_headings">
                            <xsl:with-param name="working_group" select="current-group() except ."/>
                            <xsl:with-param name="heading_level" select="1"/>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                    </chapter>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:call-template name="nest_headings">
                        <xsl:with-param name="working_group" select="current-group() except ."/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="heading_level" select="1"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="nest_headings">
    <xsl:param name="working_group"/>
    <xsl:param name="heading_level"/>

    <xsl:variable name="heading_name">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('head', string($heading_level))"/>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:if test="$heading_level &lt; 6">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="$working_group" group-starting-with="$heading_name">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="current-group()[1]/name() = $heading_name">
                    <section>
                        <xsl:call-template name="nest_headings">
                            <xsl:with-param name="working_group" select="current-group()"/>
                            <xsl:with-param name="heading_level" select="$heading_level + 1"/>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                    </section>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:call-template name="nest_headings">
                        <xsl:with-param name="working_group" select="current-group()"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="heading_level" select="$heading_level + 1"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="head1|head2|head3|head4|head5">
    <info>
        <title>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </title>
    </info>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="chaptitle">
    <info>
        <title>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </title>
    </info>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="italic">
    <emphasis role="italic">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </emphasis>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="bold">
    <emphasis role="bold">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </emphasis>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="@*">
            <xsl:copy/>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But this stylesheet fails to compile with `A variable reference is not allowed in an XSLT pattern (except in a predicate)`

A mailing list I found suggests `group-starting-with="*[name()=$heading_name]`. Using this will create the `section` nodes, but they will be empty.

Is there a way to achieve what I'm looking for?

Sample input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<book xmlns="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="5.0" role="fullText" xml:lang="en">
    <chapnumber>Chapter 1</chapnumber>
    <chaptitle>Chapter Title</chaptitle>
    <head1>Heading 1</head1>
    <para>1st paragraph</para>
    <head2>Heading 2</head2>
    <para>2nd paragraph</para>
    <head2>Heading 2 2</head2>
    <para>Final paragraph</para>
</book>
```

Expected output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<book xmlns="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="5.0" role="fullText" xml:lang="en">
    <chapter label="1">
        <info>
            <title>Chapter Title</title>
        </info>
        <section>
            <info>
                <title>Heading 1</title>
            </info>
            <para>1st paragraph</para>
            <section>
                <info>
                    <title>Heading 2</title>
                </info>
                <para>2nd paragraph</para>
            </section>
            <section>
                <info>
                    <title>Heading 2 2</title>
                </info>
                <para>Final paragraph</para>
            </section>
        </section>
    </chapter>
</book>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make sure you process the items once the grouping is done so use `<xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>` in the `xsl:otherwise`:

```
<xsl:template name="nest_headings">
    <xsl:param name="working_group"/>
    <xsl:param name="heading_level"/>

    <xsl:variable name="heading_name" select="concat('head', $heading_level)"/>

    <xsl:if test="$heading_level &lt; 6">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="$working_group" group-starting-with="*[local-name() eq $heading_name]">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="local-name() eq $heading_name">
                    <section>
                        <xsl:call-template name="nest_headings">
                            <xsl:with-param name="working_group" select="current-group()"/>
                            <xsl:with-param name="heading_level" select="$heading_level + 1"/>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                    </section>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

The `test="current-group()[1]/name() = $heading_name"` could be shortened to `test="local-name() eq $heading_name"`.
See http://xsltransform.net/pPqsHTm/1 for a full sample.

Comment: As an aside, is there any way I can shorten the expression `match="head1|head2|head3|head4|head5"` and have it match any instance of `head` followed by a digit?

Comment: Should be `match="*[matches(local-name(), '^head[0-9]$')]"`.

Comment: But in Saxon, match="head1|head2|head3..." will be much faster than using the regular expression.